# Problems with opening RStudio

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

When I try to open a freshly-installed RStudio, I am getting the following problem (and a blank application window):

```
ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error)
[errormsg=Error : package 'utils' does not have a namespace];
OCCURRED AT: core::Error r::exec::evaluateString(const std::string &, SEXP *, sexp::Protect *)
/Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:271
```

My specs:

- OS X 10.8.5,
- R 3.1.2 (installed by Homebrew),
- RStudio 0.98.1091 - Mac OS X 10.6+ (64-bit).

Before, it was working (AFAIK with R 2.*).

Any ideas how to make it working?

Comment: Why not install RStudio's standard package assembly?  I'm not surprised that there's some mismatch with `homebrew` .

Comment: For me it is not obvious why it _shouldn't_ work with `homebrew` (and I tend to install stuff with it to keep things sane). And RStudio does not come with standard R - it needs to be installed separately anyway. In any case, installing a standalone install _and_ `brew uninstall r` did help; but still, I am not sure why.

Comment: Did you try asking the RStudio forums about mixing it w/ homebrew?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: Well, the maintainer of the Mac fork of R specifically says that if you don't know why it's a potential problem, then you shouldn't do it. There are people who use the homebrew-R, but they have enough *NIX experience to do it on their own.

Comment: `brew uninstall --force r` was the winner.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue after I installed R via Homebrew. The only way I was able to fix it was to uninstall the Homebrew "version" of R.

```
brew uninstall r
```

Then reinstalling R directly from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press and hold **Ctrl** (Windows) or **⌘** (Mac) when starting RStudio
2. Choose manually a specific version of R (you may want to install it in a directory without 'spaces' or something in the path).

---

It worked like a charm for me.

- *Helping/Idea source:* https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508

Answer (score 0):

This was the case for me too, for days! Guess what, I solved it!

While installing R-Studio, after downloading *.pkg file ( not by homebrew) from the [CRAN's site](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) , select customize and deselect **R.app gui** to prevent it from installing. I think it has a nasty conflict with RStudio.

To help those googling the crash report content:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000054d8

VM Regions Near 0x54d8:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100938000 [ 9440K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rsession

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libR.dylib
```

Comment: There no need to "deselect" `R,app` if you do not install the ".pkg" file that includes the gui and just install the .tar.gz file.

Answer (score 0):

after installing r with brew, installing rstudio failed (the downloaded size had also been about 5mb so i was already scare). I just downloded rstudio and installed it in the Applications folder, without uninstalling r and it worked. installing and updating packages has also been a breeze for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands worked for me:

```
┌─[ricardoramos]@[falcon]:~
└──> $ sudo mkdir .rstudio-deskop
[sudo] password for ricardoramos: 
┌─[ricardoramos]@[falcon]:~
└──> $ sudo chown -R ricardoramos ~/.rstudio-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Install your **R** again in a folder (without any space (**Program Files** folder has space) in the folder names like the following image)

[image]

Then open Rstudio (pressing **Ctrl** then click on icon) select new installed path for R

[image]

This solved the issue. In MAC use the command button.